# Find cell neighbors of a given edge in a 2D grid

Tags: computational-geometry, search-algorithms

In the figure below, cells are labeled row wise, and edges are labeled counter clockwise.  That is, vertices 1' and 2' form edge #1, vertices 2' and 5' form edge #2, vertices 5' and 8' form edge #7, etc.

- vertices 1' and 2' form edge #1
- vertices 2' and 5' form edge #2
- vertices 4' and 5' form edge #3
- vertices 1' and 4' form edge #4
- vertices 2' and 3' form edge #5
- vertices 3' and 6' form edge #6
- vertices 6' and 5' form edge #7
- vertices 5' and 8' form edge #8
- vertices 7' and 8' form edge #9
- vertices 4' and 7' form edge #10
- vertices 6' and 9' form edge #11
- vertices 8' and 9' form edge #12

> Question: given an edge number (and/or the vertices that form it), is there a way to algorithmically
>   compute its corresponding cell neighbors?

[image]

Comment: @adrianN  I've only been able to come up with a brute force procedure.  I have a code that will make a look up table.  I initially loop over every cell.  I then loop over each edge of the cell, assigning the cell # to the edge.  This double counts the interior edges.  I then do another pass that checks to see if an edge has been listed twice, then I can obtain the complete non redundant cell neighbor list.

Comment: Any hints?  References?

Comment: I think you should add edge numbers for *all* edges on your graph, otherwise it's unclear how you got number 7 for (5',8')

Comment: @HEKTO added the requested information.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The labelling of the edges seems entirely arbitrary so there doesn't seem to be any kind of general question here, just "Give me an algorithm that computes this arbitrary function from $\{1, \dots, 9\}^2\to\{1, \dots, 12\}$. Since there's only one function to compute, on a small, fixed, finite domain, there aren't really any efficiency issues and if you're looking for "something better than table lookup", that's essentially a code golfing exercise, which is off-topic, here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any special algorithm.  There are only 12 edges, so it's enough to simply use a switch statement with 12 cases.  Or, you can use 12 if statements.  Any of these will have $O(1)$ running time, since there are only finitely many cases, so they are (asymptotically) as good as any other "algorithm".

Comment: What if I need to increase the number of cells (which also increases the number of edges)?  In particular, if I have $M=2^N$ cells there are $2*M*(M+1)$ edges, which is a lot of switch statements (for sufficiently large $N$).

Comment: @user107904, well, yup, that's different -- my answer won't work for that.  I can only answer the question that was asked.  If that's the question you want an answer to, I suggest you edit the question to explain what you are really trying to accomplish; and show us what approaches you've considered.